# Filling not observed observations

Tags: r

I want to make a time series with the frequency a date and time is observed. The raw data looked something like this:

```
dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm
28-2-2018 0:12
28-2-2018 11:16
28-2-2018 12:12
28-2-2018 13:22
28-2-2018 14:23
28-2-2018 14:14
28-2-2018 16:24
```

The date and time format is in the wrong way for R, so I had to adjust it:

```
extracted_times <- as.POSIXct(bedrijf.CSV$viewed_at, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

I ordered the data with frequency in a table using the following code:

```
timeserieswithoutzeros <- table(extracted_times)
```

The data looks something like this now:

```
2018-02-28 00:11:00 2018-02-28 01:52:00 2018-02-28 03:38:00                   
                  1                   2                   5 
2018-02-28 04:10:00 2018-02-28 04:40:00 2018-02-28 04:45:00                  
                  2                   1                   1
```

As you may see there are a lot of unobserved dates and times. 
I want to add these unobserved dates and times with the frequency of 0. 
I tried the complete function, but the error states that it can't best used, because I use `as.POSIXct()`. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Please post reproducible data using dput(). What is the range of unobserved dates you want to see?

Comment: Apart from @BillO'Brien's doubt, the range of date/time, what is the resolution, minutes?

Comment: Hi, I want the table to begin at the earliest date and time in the data and I want to end it at the last date and time. The resolution is in minutes I think, seen the data output when I order it

Comment: Initialize a sequence with `seq` (from min to max by a step of a minute) then merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentinoned in the comments by @eric-lecoutre, you can combine your observations with a sequence begining at the earliest ending at the last date using `seq` and subtract 1 of the frequency table.

```
timeseriesWithzeros <- table(c(extracted_times, seq(min(extracted_times), max(extracted_times), "1 min")))-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following is what you want.
First, coerce the data to class `"POSIXt"` and create the sequence of all date/time between `min` and `max` by steps of 1 minute.

```
bedrijf.CSV$viewed_at <- as.POSIXct(bedrijf.CSV$viewed_at, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
new <- seq(min(bedrijf.CSV$viewed_at), 
           max(bedrijf.CSV$viewed_at), 
           by = "1 mins")
tmp <- data.frame(viewed_at = new)
```

Now see if these values are in the original data.

```
tmp$viewed <- tmp$viewed_at %in% bedrijf.CSV$viewed_at
tbl <- xtabs(viewed ~ viewed_at, tmp)

sum(tbl != 0)
#[1] 7
```

Final clean up.

```
rm(new, tmp)
```